# Converting an array to a function arguments list

Tags: javascript, arrays, arguments

Is it possible to convert an array in JavaScript into a function argument sequence? Example:

```
run({ "render": [ 10, 20, 200, 200 ] });

function run(calls) {
  var app = .... // app is retrieved from storage
  for (func in calls) {
    // What should happen in the next line?
    var args = ....(calls[func]);
    app[func](args);  // This is equivalent to app.render(10, 20, 200, 200);
  }
}
```

Comment: Check for a similar question also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856059/passing-an-array-as-a-function-parameter-in-javascript

Comment: I guess it doesn't matter, but it seems odd that this older question is the one marked as the duplicate of the newer, referenced question?

Answer (score 336, accepted):

Yes. In current versions of JS you can use:

```
app[func]( ...args );
```

Users of ES5 and older will need to use the `.apply()` method:

```
app[func].apply( this, args );
```

Read up on these methods at MDN:

- [.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)
- [spread "..." operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator#A_better_apply) (not to be confused with the related [rest "..." parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) operator: it's good to read up on both!)

Comment: window does not seem to be necessary.

Comment: This doesn't work if you want to call a function within an object – e.g. the following doesn't work: `window.document.execCommand.apply(window,["insertHorizontalRule",false])`

Comment: That's because, in your case, you should specify `window.document` as the first argument, not just `window`:

`window.document.execCommand.apply(window.document, ... )`

Comment: `window` actually makes no sense in non-browser JavaScript frameworks such as NodeJS, therefore I'd suggest removing it from the answer.

Comment: If you can use ES6 features you can even use `f(...[1,2,3])`.

Comment: Another good idea. Done!

Answer (score 126):

### A very readable example from another post on similar topic:

```
var args = [ 'p0', 'p1', 'p2' ];

function call_me (param0, param1, param2 ) {
    // ...
}

// Calling the function using the array with apply()
call_me.apply(this, args);
```

And [here a link to the original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856059/passing-an-array-as-a-function-parameter-in-javascript) that I personally liked for its readability

Comment: If that works, why won't this work? `document.body.setAttribute.apply( this, ["foo", "bar"] );`  I need to send variable arguments to various object methods with different argument requirements. _Quick edit: Apparently `this` has to be document.body, or whatever the parent is_

Comment: On a Typescript constructor this will raise an error: `Only a void function can be called with the 'new' keyword`

Answer (score 25):

```
app[func].apply(this, args);
```

Answer (score 12):

You might want to take a look at a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676721/calling-dynamic-function-with-dynamic-parameters-in-javascript) posted on Stack Overflow. It uses the `.apply()` method to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

@bryc - yes, you could do it like this:

```
Element.prototype.setAttribute.apply(document.body,["foo","bar"])
```

But that seems like a lot of work and obfuscation compared to:

```
document.body.setAttribute("foo","bar")
```