# redis zunionstore dynamically pass the sets

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, runtime

I want to use the zunionstore command on sets which i define at runtime, they are fetched dynamically so i never know what the sets are that i have to pass to the function.

syntax of zunionstore:

> ZUNIONSTORE destination numkeys key [key ...] [WEIGHTS weight [weight ...]] [AGGREGATE SUM|MIN|MAX]

the `parsed` array contains the names of the sets.

```
client.zunionstore
        (
            'out',                
            parsed.length,
            parsed,
            function (err, res)
            {
                console.log(err); 
                if(!err)
                {
                    client.zrevrange('out', 0, -1, 'withscores', function (err, res)
                    {
                        console.log(res);
                        if(!err)
                        {
                            //do stuff
                        }
                    });                          
                }
            }
        );
```

as you can see i tried to pass the array containing the names but this doesn't work..

the error i get:

```
[Error: ERR syntax error]
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you mean that you are having problems passing an array to a function? put all arguments into an array and call `apply` on the function: [Passing an array as a function parameter in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856059/passing-an-array-as-a-function-parameter-in-javascript)

so, you have your `parsed` array, just add to it the other things like your `'out'`, `parsed.length`, etc, and call `client.zunionstore.apply(this, array)`.

Comment: Thanks it worked, i just had to change the context to client instead of this :)