# Array as function parameters/arguments

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

Can I pass an array as parameters/arguments in a function?

For example, this works:

```
key(0, arrowRight, 'regX', anchorLast, 8, 'quartInOut', 175);
```

This, however, doesn't:

```
var banana = [0, arrowRight, 'regX', anchorLast, 8, 'quartInOut', 175]
key(banana);
```

returning `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined` from within the `key()` function. What's `undefined` here is what should have been `arrowRight` (an object).

I've tried searching for answers, and most [prescribe the use of `.apply()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856059/passing-an-array-as-a-function-parameter-in-javascript) (or `.call()`), but I'm not sure how to apply this to my situation. I'm not even if it's the same problem (still a Javascript beginner).

I didn't post the `key()` function here, because I don't think it's relevant.

Comment: What did you try wrt `apply`?

Comment: Oh, you added `.apply()` to your question? Or was it there all along? I only remember seeing `.call()` there at first.

Comment: @CrazyTrain I mistyped so I added it later :)

Comment: Oh, alright. Wasn't sure if I just overlooked it.

Comment: Drive-by comment: Just pay attention to the fact that in your first example you're passing in 7 parameters, and in the second you're only passing in 1! **That's** the difference, and that's what `apply` does: takes an array and converts its elements to individual parameters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, use `.apply()` to invoke your `key` function and distribute an Array or Array-like object as individual arguments to the function.

```
key.apply(this, banana);
```

---

The first argument to `.apply()` sets the `this` value of your `key` function. Here I just used the enclosing `this` value.

The second argument is the collection of arguments to be passed to your `key` function.