# How to pass dynamic data in highchart using angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, charts, highcharts, linechart

I have used line chart.
Here is the link of line chart  http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/qyntd1xa/ 
I have stuck in pass dynamically data in line chart.
How to pass dynamically data in line chart.
i am new in angular js
here is my controller function  code-

```
$scope.updatedays   =   function(){ 
        $scope.data =   $scope.getdata();
        console.log($scope.data);

        Highcharts.chart('cont2', {
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['MON 12', 'TUE 13', 'WED 14', 'THU 15', 'FRI 16', 'SAT 17', 'SUN 18']
            },

            series: [{
                data: [1.5, 5.5, 3.0, 2.5, 4.5, 3, 2]
            }]
        });
    }
```

I tryed pass dynamically data but i getting error in  Highcharts.

Comment: What errors are you getting? And what does "dynamic data" look like? Be specific when you post a question

Comment: How about using the [highchart-ng](https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your data and your categories in two separate arrays that match up by index and then use those two arrays as your values.

For example:

```
xAxis: {
    categories: myCategoriesArray
},

series: [{
    data: myDataArray
}]
```

If you want to pass the arrays into your function, check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856059/passing-an-array-as-a-function-parameter-in-javascript).