# Passing array of arguments for a function which expects N number of arguments

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, .when

Basically what I'm trying to do is similar to this;

```
function methodX(arg1, arg2, ...) {}
methodX([arg1, arg2, arg3]);
```

In actual scenario I have an array (`cbInfo`), and I'm trying to use it with `jQuery.when()` as shown below and it doesn't seems to be working. So is there a way to pass array of arguments for a function which expects N number of arguments?

```
var cbInfo = [
    {
        templatePath: 'templates/level.html',
        callback: renderLevels
    },
    {
        templatePath: 'templates/alert.html',
        callback: renderAlerts
    }
];

function loadTemplates(cbInfo, cb) {
    var ajaxes = [],
        callbacks = [];

    cbInfo.forEach(function (elem) {
        ajaxes.push($.ajax({type: "GET", url: elem.templatePath}));
        callbacks.push(elem.callback)
    });

    $.when(ajaxes).then(
        function () {
            var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
            callbacks.forEach(function (elem, index) {
                elem(args[index]);
            });
            cb();
        },
        function () {
            // failure
            console.error("loadTemplates() : could not load UI templates.")
        }
    );
}
```

---

**UPDATE**:
Both apply and spread operator worked in other situations. But I'm trying to solve this for this specific situation. I tried using $.when().apply(null, ajaxes), but then it throws `Uncaught TypeError: $.when(...).apply is not a function` How to overcome this? Moreover, I need to support ES5 too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing an array as a function parameter in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856059/passing-an-array-as-a-function-parameter-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using ES6, there's a perfect way to handle this: the Spread operator

```
functionName(...args);
```

> Example: it is common to use Function.prototype.apply in cases where
>   you want to use an array as arguments to a function.
>
> `function myFunction(x, y, z) { } var args = [0, 1, 2];`
>   `myFunction.apply(null, args);`
>
> With ES6 spread you can now write the above as:
>
> `function myFunction(x, y, z) { } var args = [0, 1, 2];`
>   `myFunction(...args);`
>
> Any argument in the argument list can use the spread syntax and it can be used multiple times.
>
> `function myFunction(v, w, x, y, z) { } var args = [0, 1];`
>   `myFunction(-1, ...args, 2, ...[3]);`

Please refer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) for more details

Working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/arj7x4gb/)

Comment: Added a working fiddle with `Array.prototype.apply`. This should work for you: https://jsfiddle.net/arj7x4gb/1/

Answer (score 4):

You can use function [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) for that:

```
methodX.apply(null, [arg1, arg2, arg3]);
```

Like it says in the documentation:

> The apply() method calls a function with a given this value and
>   arguments provided as an array (or an array-like object).