# Math.max returns null on variables?

Tags: javascript, arrays, math

So I am building a piece of JavaScript code that returns an array of the largest numbers from each of the provided sub-arrays.

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
var array = [];
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
// return arr[i].join() on this line gives 4,5,1,3
array.push(Math.max(arr[i].join()));
}
return array;
}

largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
```

My question is why the:
`Math.max(arr[i].join())`
 returns a `null value`?

If I return 
`arr[i].join()`  on the previous line (as in code comment) it returns to me `4,5,1,3` for the 1st iteration. If I put in `Math.max(4,5,1,3)` it returns `5`which is what I want.

Assigning the `arr[i].join()` to a variable and then putting in `Math.max` also returns `null`. I would run the`Math.max`through a reduce function, but it won't let me run a function through a loop.

I'm sure there is a simple reason why this doesn't work, but I can't find an explanation anywhere. I don't need help with a solution to the overall problem - just help with understanding why the `Math.max` won't work.

Answer (score 6):

`Math.max(4,5,1,3)` and `Math.max('4,5,1,3')` are two very different operations. Passing a **string** that contains comma separated values is *not* the same as passing **multiple arguments**:

```js
function foo(x, y, z) {
   console.log('x', x);
   console.log('y', y);
   console.log('z', z);
}

foo(1,2,3);
foo('1,2,3');
foo([1,2,3].join());
```

`Math.max` expects to be passed multiple *numbers*, not a single *string*.

---

The question you should be asking is:

[How can I pass the elements of an array as arguments to a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2856059/218196)

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. Appreciate all the responses and explanations.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the array with math max, problem is max wants a list of arguments. So we use apply to do it

```js
var arr = [1,4,5,9]
var max = Math.max.apply( Math, arr );
console.log(max);
```

And using map with it, you can get all the largest numbers

```js
var nums = [[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]

var result = nums.map(arr =>  Math.max.apply(Math, arr))
//var result = nums.map(function(arr){ return Math.max.apply(Math, arr)})
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks, these are the solutions I will apply.

Answer (score 1):

As wrote in the document,and mentioned in comments:

> The join() method joins all elements of an array (or an array-like object) into a string.

Therefore, remove `join` and rewrite `max` like the following:

```js
function largestOfFour(arr) {
    var array = [];
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        array.push(Math.max(...arr[i]));
    }
    return array;
}

console.log(largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]));
```

Comment: Thanks, I originally tried this solution, but my console wasn't running the necessary ES6.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function largest(arr) {
  var array = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    array.push(Math.max.apply(null, arr[i]));
  }

  return array;
}

var array = [
  [4, 5, 1, 3],
  [13, 27, 18, 26],
  [32, 35, 37, 39],
  [1000, 1001, 857, 1]
];

var result = largest(array);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max#Return_value) on the return value of `Math.max`

> The largest of the given numbers. If at least one of the arguments cannot be converted to a number, NaN is returned.

If you actually observe the `array` variable in your function, you'll see `[NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN]` at the end of the loop. That is a indication that *at least one of the arguments cannot be converted to a number*. And if you just check one of the inputs to the `Math.max` function, you'll see what's going wrong

```js
// Random array
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4];

// The join
console.log(a.join()); // "1,2,3,4"

// Try to convert the join to a Number
console.log(Number(a.join())); // NaN

// Try getting a max out of the join. Your case here
console.log(Math.max(a.join())); // NaN
```