# Passing in variable amount of parameters to a function that looks like "function(*x)" JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I can't seem to find an answer to this question because I don't really know what this is called, if there's a solution already point me there.

I'm trying to use this from [underscore.js](https://underscorejs.org/)

```
_.intersection(*arrays)
```

I understand I can use the function like so:

```
var intersection = _.intersection(['a','b'], ['a','c'])
```

and get
`['a']` back.

I have a variable amount of arrays however, so I want to do something like this:

```
var intersection = _.intersection(array for array in my_arrays)
```

I understand I could do this:

```
var intersection = my_arrays[0];
my_arrays.forEach(arr => intersection = _.intersection(intersection, arr) )
```

But that doesn't seem clean. How can this be done?
Thanks.

Comment: do you habe an example of the given data and the wanted result?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing an array as a function parameter in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856059/passing-an-array-as-a-function-parameter-in-javascript)

Comment: No matter how a JavaScript function is declared, you can pass as many arguments as you want when you call the function. Whether it works or not depends on the particular function involved.

Comment: `_.intersection(...arrays)`?

Comment: That's just the documentation convention for the Underscore library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most modern browsers support ES6 so you can use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to do this:

```js
const my_arrays = [[1, 2], [1, 3, 4], [1, 5, 6, 7]];
dummy_intersection(...my_arrays);

function dummy_intersection(...arrays) {
  console.log(arrays[0]);
}
```

On a side note, it's generally considered a [better idea to use lodash than underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13869090/3930247).

Comment: That worked :) Thanks. Fairly new to JS, don't really understand the spread. Will read up on it.

Comment: Yeah sorry I didn't really know.

Comment: @MarkMan My pleasure. Please accept the answer if it answered your question.

Comment: @technophyle I can in 3 minutes :)

Comment: @Pointy Yes I can, but the whole point of the question was to avoid that, because my_arrays is variable... I'm using this in Vue.js and the arrays it gets passed through a component are always variable :P