# How to pass an arrays as a function arguments in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Like in the title. I want to pass a few arrays as a function parameters.

```
var array1 = ["a", "b", "c"];
var array2 = ["d", "e"];
var array3 = ["f", "g"];

function arraysFunction(param1, param2, param3){
    var a = param1;
    var b = param2;
    var c = param3;
}
```

How to do that?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What are error are you getting when you try to do a: arraysFunction(array1, array2, array3)? Functions are first class objects in javascript so your code should work from what I can tell.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting a Javascript array to a function arguments list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316371/converting-a-javascript-array-to-a-function-arguments-list)

Comment: What you have should work, make sure your calling the right variables.

Comment: This problem is similar [Passing an array as a function parameter in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856059/passing-an-array-as-a-function-parameter-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

```
var array1 = ["a", "b", "c"];
var array2 = ["d", "e"];
var array3 = ["f", "g"];

function arraysFunction(any, name, youwant){
    var a = any;
    var b = name;
    var c = youwant;
}

arraysFunction(array1,array2,array3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You pass an array same as any other variable.

```
function foo( param1 ){
    var a = param1;
    return param1;
}
var array1 = ["a","b","c"];
console.log(foo(array1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I will describe in more detail.
This is my ajax function

```
self.buyAlbum = function () {
albumViewModel.lists.removeAll();
    $.ajax({
        url: "api/list/",
        type: "GET",
        success: function (data) {
            //alert(data.Converw);
            albumViewModel.lists.push(new addItemForm(data.Coverw, data.PublishHousew, data.PublishYearw, data.Carrierw));    
        }
    });
};
```

And this is my viewmodel

```
function addItemForm(c, h, y, ca) {
var self = this;

self.Coverw = x;
self.PublishHousew = ko.observableArray(h);
self.PublishYearw = ko.observableArray();
self.Carrierw = ko.observableArray();


//self.Coverw = ko.observableArray(['sth1', 'sth2']);
//self.PublishHousew = ko.observableArray(['sth3', 'sth4']);
//self.PublishYearw = ko.observableArray([1990, 1991, 1992]);
//self.Carrierw = ko.observableArray(['sth5', 'sth6']);
}
```

I use knockoutjs in asp.net mvc.
In the application view I have form with four `@Html.DropDownList` element.
As options in dropdownlists I want use my arrays. When I use this, it's OK

```
 //self.Coverw = ko.observableArray(['sth1', 'sth2']);
//self.PublishHousew = ko.observableArray(['sth3', 'sth4']);
//self.PublishYearw = ko.observableArray([1990, 1991, 1992]);
//self.Carrierw = ko.observableArray(['sth5', 'sth6']);
```

but this `self.Coverw = x;` and this `self.PublishHousew = ko.observableArray(h);` the dropdownlists are empty.
I use `alert(data.Converw);` and it's work.