# JavaScript convert string into literal comma list

Tags: javascript, string

Is there a way to convert `"1,2"` into `1,2` using native JS without some sort of wrapper?

`"1,2".someMagic() \\ 1,2`

Ultimately, I want to pass this as arguments to a function.

Comment: can you provide more example ?

Comment: Ideally, I want to call some `function(1,2)` by converting `"1,2"` from a string into args.

Comment: The exact thing you are trying to achieve is impossible. Think about it: `func(1, 2)` is parsed as a function call with two arguments. I.e. the engine already knows, before executing the code what, this is, just by parsing it. OTOH `"1,2"` is a string literal. You want to transform it to something else *at runtime*, i.e. *after* all the code has been parsed. You want to convert a runtime value to a syntax construct. Syntax cannot be changed or created at runtime. The only way to do that is to use `eval`, I guess that's not what you want to use.

Comment: @FelixKling I actually tried and it returns `2`. `eval` would work for this but it's not working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, no there is no way to convert `"1,2"` to literally `1,2`. Because it is invalid type. 1,2 is better represented as an array

You can use [.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) like below to send 1,2 as parameters (array format) to the function someMagic

```
someMagic.apply(context, [1,2]);
```

Apply would call someMagic and send 1,2 as parameters

Answer (score 1):

```
function doSomething(param1, param2) {
    return parseInt(param1)+parseInt(param2);
};

doSomething.apply(this, "1,2".split(","));
// returns 3
```

Perhaps this thread [Converting an array to a function arguments list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316371/converting-a-javascript-array-to-a-function-arguments-list) may be of interest to you.

Answer (score 0):

Using split is the answer.

```
var string = "1,2";
var splitString = string.split(","); //use , as an parameter to split
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Comment: That converts to an array

Comment: And that array can then be passed to `apply`. `someMagic.apply(null, string.split(","))`

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "1,2,3,4,5,6";

var arr=[];

function process(str){
  // split the string into tokens
     arr = str.split(",");

     // go through each array element
  arr.forEach(function(val,index,ar){
    // convert each element into integer
    var temp = parseInt(val);
    // repopulate array
    arr[index] = temp;
  });

}

process(str);

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: please add an explanation to your answer.

Comment: It's best if you add some commentary and not just toss code out there.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to user3146092's answer, this one will not rely on your function having to `parseInt`.

```
someMagic.apply(this, '1,2'.split(',').map(function(n) { return parseInt(n, 10); }));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of numbers and pass them as your arguments, that in fact, is the best way to do it in JavaScript.

```
var nums = "1,2,3"
  .split(",")
  .map(function (num) { return parseInt(num, 10) });
```

Now you can pass `nums` as your arguments.