# Pass variable from array into a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I have this function:

```
function getTotal () {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        total += args[i];
    }

    return total;
}
```

Lets say that I have an array that is filled with numbers and I do not know the length of it:

```
var numArray = [ ..., ... ];
```

How can I call the function `getTotal` by passing in every element in the `numArray` as a parameter?

Comment: This looks like a homework.

Comment: >by passing in every element in the numArray as a parameter?
**why** would you do that when you can just pass the array?

Comment: @TimothyGroote this is not the actual function that I have, just a simplified version of it to focus on this single concept

Comment: @serdar.sanri its not homework lol

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting an array to a function arguments list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316371/converting-an-array-to-a-function-arguments-list)

Answer (score 5):

In ES6 you can do this:

```
getTotal(...numArray);
```

It called *Spread syntax*. For more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Comment: Oh, sorry, i'll update the answer with EN version =)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Comment: This syntax KICKS ASS, ty for mentioning it instead standard apply pattern

Answer (score 4):

You can call the function using [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply). It will pass the Array as arguments to your function.

```js
function getTotal () {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        total += args[i];
    }

    return total;
}

var numArray = [1,2,3,4];

console.log( getTotal.apply( null, numArray ) );
```

Keep in mind you have a typo in your for loop. Should be `args.length`, instead of `arg.length`.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this. Hope it helps

```
var sum = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].reduce(add, 0);

function add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do this:

```
function getTotal (args) {
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        total += args[i];
    }

    return total;
}

var numArray = [1,2,3];
console.log(getTotal(numArray)); //6
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the spread operator, you may also want to ES6ify your code:

```
function getTotal(...vals){
  return vals.reduce((a,b)=>a+b,0);
}

getTotal(...[1,2,4]);
```

Comment: Spread is not an operator, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/37151966/. Note that `...vals` parameter at `function getTotal(...vals){}` is rest element, not spread element