# javascript array parameter list

Tags: javascript, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calling dynamic function with dynamic parameters in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676721/calling-dynamic-function-with-dynamic-parameters-in-javascript)

I have an array representing the parameters I need to pass to a function call.  How can I construct this function call dynamically?

e.g.

```
function constructRequest(params) {
   //params is an array of params to be sent to myFunction()

   myFunction(params[0],params[1], ... , params[i]);

   //myFunction() needs to have the array deconstructed and is ready 
   // to accept optional params
}
```

Thanks

Comment: The tl;dr version of the other question is to use `myFunction.apply(window, params)`.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the other question.  The other question is asking about passing functions.

Answer (score 4):

Use `arguments`:

```
function A()
{
    alert( arguments[0] ); // 1
    alert( arguments[1] ); // 2
    alert( arguments[2] ); // 3
}

A(1, 2, 3);
```

[More info on MDC (Mozilla Develop Center)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Functions#Using_the_arguments_object).

Comment: You've got this the other way around. bba has an array already and needs to break it down in order to call another function.

Comment: I dont think this answers my question..maybe I'm wrong - could you put it in terms of my example code?

Comment: @bba: That's what I understand from your question. Provide more info then.