# Getting the function arguments in javascript like in PHP

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calling dynamic function with dynamic parameters in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676721/calling-dynamic-function-with-dynamic-parameters-in-javascript)
>   [javascript array parameter list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917243/javascript-array-parameter-list)

I'm looking for the Javascript equivalent of the following functionality I use in PHP:

```
function myfunc()
{
     $arg_arr = array();
     $arg_arr = func_get_args();

     $my_arg_val_1 = (!isset($arg_arr[1]) || ($arg_arr[1] == '')) ? true : $arg_arr[1];
}
```

Basically, I'm trying to get the function arguments. I want to write a javascript function to take one argument, but I want to add some code to do a few things with the second and third argument if it is provided, but I'm not sure how to pull this off.

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You could just have one argument that's an array (I'm not a JS expert though, there might be a better way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript there is [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) variable available in each function. It looks like an array which contains all arguments passed to a function:

```
function myfunc() {
    var arg1 = arguments[0],
        arg2 = arguments[1],
        argc = arguments.length;
}

myfunc(1, "abc");  // arg1 = 1,
                   // arg2 = "abc",
                   // argc = 2
```

Comment: Thanks. The simpler the better I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) variable.

It's not an array (it's an "Array-like object", which has a few differences with a standard array), but you can convert it to a real array this way :

```
function myfunc() {
    var argArray = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments );
    /* ... do whatever you want */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is a dupe, but the answer is straightforward:

```
function foo() {
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    alert(arguments[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Those function you have been ported to js:

- [func_get_arg](http://phpjs.org/functions/func_get_arg/)
- [func_get_args](http://phpjs.org/functions/func_get_args/)
- [isset](http://phpjs.org/functions/isset/)
- [array](http://phpjs.org/functions/array/)

**[{php} .js](http://phpjs.org/)**

Comment: But should probably not be used except for looking how to use the underlying JS features.

Comment: @Nabil Thanks, I use PHPJS quite extensively but in this case, it seems a bit overkill for the circumstance.

Comment: @Chuck Ugwuh, array()... yes, but not the other functions