# alternative to eval in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an object created which belongs to particular class.

```
            var schCom1 = Server.CreateObject(ArchiveProgID);
```

Now, this object gives call to method which is dynamically decided.

```
            fnName += "(";
        for (counter=0;counter<fnArgs.length;counter++)
        {
            if(counter > 0)
                fnName += ",";
            fnName += fnArgs[counter];
        }
        fnName += ")";
        writeComment("Ready to call method:" + "schCom1." + fnName);
        // according to the type of recurrance, call method
        eval("schCom1."+ fnName);
```

Is there any substitution possible to this eval call ?

Any Help will be valuable .

Thanks in advance.
Tazim.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling dynamic function with dynamic parameters in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676721/calling-dynamic-function-with-dynamic-parameters-in-javascript)

Comment: You should use `fnName+="("+fnArgs.join(",")+")"` instead of that `for` loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided that fnName really is a name of a method of the schCom1 object:

```
schCom1[fnName].apply(schCom1,fnArgs);
```

Basically, the `apply` method for function objects allow you to call the function and provide the context (parent object) and arguments. And the `apply` method expects function arguments to be supplied as an array, which is useful in this case.

See the documentation of the `apply` method for more info:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/apply

there's also the `call` method which does something similar but expects function arguments as a regular argument list:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/call

Comment: thanx a lot . answer was really helpful for understanding the concept

Comment: fnName is not the real name of function name of schCom1 . fnName = Request("fnName").  it should be schCom1[Request("fnName")].apply(schCom1,fnArgs);

Answer (score 2):

You can use a more simpler

```
schCom1[fname].apply(schCom1, fnArgs)
```

that would replace all your code up there

Comment: Don't you mean `schCom1[fnName].apply`? Other than that, nice answer :)

Comment: @Aistina yes I did, thanks ! (didn't see the bloody point there)

Comment: `this` points probably to a global variable in this context, it really should be `schCom1` instead