# Why is shift() working improperly on my args from a dynamically called function using apply()?

Tags: javascript, function, apply, shift

I'm working on a dynamic validation system. For some reason, shift() on the args array mainfunc passes to validateNumber does not act properly. Here's the code with output in comments next to alert boxes:

```
function mainfunc (func){
    //this calls the function validateNumber and passes args to it.
    this[func].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
}

function validateNumber(args) {
    alert(args); //this functions normally. for example, displays fish,3,5
    var text = args.shift; //would expect this to return 'fish', right?
    alert(text); //instead of 'fish' alerts 'function shift() { [native code] }'. This is the problem.
    var minimum = args.shift;
    var maximum = args.shift;
    return text;
}

validationArgs = classList[i].split('-');
    functionName = validationArgs.shift();
    validationArgs.unshift($(this).val());
    mainfunc(functionName, validationArgs); //calls mainfunc which calls the function
```

I'm stumped as to why this behaves this way. Note: I cribbed mainfunc from this StackOverflow answer: [Calling dynamic function with dynamic parameters in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676721/calling-dynamic-function-with-dynamic-parameters-in-javascript/676728#676728)

Edit: Oh, my goodness. I am an idiot. I even use shift() correctly in the title of the question! Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
var text = args.shift;
```

is not a method call, you want:

```
var text = args.shift();
```

All your original does is assigns the `shift` method from `args` to `text`, hence your:

```
function shift() { [native code] }
```

output in your `alert`. Doing a `args.shift` won't have any effect on `args` so these two:

```
var minimum = args.shift;
var maximum = args.shift;
```

just give you two more reference's to `args.shift` without changing `args` at all.

Answer (score 2):

```
var text = args.shift; //would expect this to return 'fish', right?
```

Wrong. You need the parens to call a function. Otherwise you will just get the function itself (which you saw in the alert message).

```
var text = args.shift();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var text = args.shift; //would expect this to return 'fish', right?
```

*shift* is a method, did you mean to call it or assign a reference?

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete the explanation here of what was going on:

```
var p = args.shift;
```

is a method assignment.  You've assigned the function `shift` found on the object `args` to the variable `p`, but not actually executed that function.  At this point, `p` contains a reference to the function shift.  Thus, when you `alert(p)`, you see a native code reference (that's the code behind the shift function).

Whereas:

```
var p = args.shift();
```

finds the function named `shift` on the `args` object and executes it without any parameters and then assigns the return value of that method to the variable `p`.