# Calling arbitrary function with Javascript 'apply'

Tags: javascript

I want to pass a varying number of argument to varying functions. I set up this basic test:

```
function overview(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
    console.info('arg1 is ' + arg1);
    console.info('arg2 is ' + arg2);
    console.info('arg3 is ' + arg3);
}

function modules(method, args) {
    this[method].apply(null, args);
}

modules('overview', new Array('test1', 'test2'));​
```

So, I use 'apply' to pass an array with arguments via the 'modules' function to the 'overview' function. This works fine, *except* for the `this[method]` part. I read about this in this Q&A: [Calling dynamic function with dynamic parameters in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676721/calling-dynamic-function-with-dynamic-parameters-in-javascript) and it seems marvelous. However, I keep getting 'TypeError' errors and I can't figure out how to resolve this.

Of course, I could use a `switch` within the modules function to call the correct method, but that is unnecessary bulk (hopefully!). I've made a JSFiddle to 'fiddle' with: http://jsfiddle.net/QFpRc/. Hope anyone can solve and/or explain this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` does not make sense in your context.

You have to define the functions in the global scope, or on another namespace, and use `window`, or the name of that namespace instead of `this`.

```
// Globally:    
function modules(method, args) {
    window[method].apply(null, args);
}
modules('overview', ['test1', 'test2']);​

// Locally:
var namespace = {};
namespace.overview = overview; // Defined previously
function modules(method, args) {
    namespace[method].apply(null, args);
}
modules('overview', ['test1', 'test2']);​
```

If you want to use this method locally, without predefining a namespace, there is no other option than using `eval`:

```
// Locally
function modules(method, args) {
    eval(method).apply(null, args);
}
modules('overview', ['test1', 'test2']);​
```

### Expanding the implementation:

If you want to handle unknown functions without throwing errors, use:

```
function modules(method, args) {
    var ns = window; // or namespace (method 2)    or eval(method)  (method 3)
    if (ns.hasOwnProperty(method) && typeof ns.method === 'function') {
        ns.apply(null, args);
    } else {
        console.log(' Unknown method: ' + method);
    }
}
```

### Demos

1. Global: http://jsfiddle.net/QFpRc/4/
2. Local + namespace: http://jsfiddle.net/QFpRc/3/
3. Local + eval: http://jsfiddle.net/QFpRc/2/

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. When I use `window` instead of `this`, the result is the same. Also usage of `this` was suggested in the SO question I mentioned, and the rest of the code looks roughly the same. So why can 'they' use it and I not? The namespace and eval solutions both work great, though eval looks way simpler. But can't eval do evil here?

Comment: @kasimir Have a look at the demos at the bottom of my answer. Your code does **not** work, because you have selected the `"onload"` option in the checkbox. This **wraps your code in `window.onload = function() { ..your code.. }`**, causing your code to be **local instead of global**.

Comment: So it does. Wasn't aware of that, the whole namespace thing still seems tricky to me now and then. Thanks for elaborating.

Comment: Hm... I've implemented this like in demo 1, but I've discovered that this doesn't work in IE 8... Any ideas on a solution?

Comment: @kasimir I have successfully tested demo 1 (see http://jsfiddle.net/QFpRc/5/) in IE8. Are you sure that you've implemented it correctly? (**[screenshot of demo 1 in IE8](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TrJmA.png)**).

Comment: That (5) works. And when I ran 4 again, it worked, which puzzled me. But actually, it probably was my own fault, because I was watching a console from a different IE and so I got something like `console undefined`. Anyway, my issue seemed to be that sometimes there are no arguments, which IE doesn't like. Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/QFpRc/6. I solved it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/QFpRc/7

Comment: @kasimir  `window[method].apply(null, args || []);` (added `|| []`) will solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your reference to `this` in the `modules` function declaration points to the `modules` objects. Since `modules` doesn't have an 'overview' property, there is no 'overview' method to invoke. As @Rob W stated, you could explicitly reference the global `window` object, where your functions are defined, or you could define your own object:

```
var myObj = {
    overview: function(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
        console.info('arg1 is ' + arg1);
        console.info('arg2 is ' + arg2);
        console.info('arg3 is ' + arg3);
    },

    modules: function(method, args) {
        this[method].apply(null, args);
    }
};

myObj.modules('overview', new Array('test1', 'test2'));
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/QFpRc/1/ for a live example.

Comment: Thanks, this gave me some interesting ideas for refactoring my code someday. But for now, Rob W's solution is more straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will perform faster if you used Function.prototype.bind instead of passing parameters thru a proxy function. Bind will save processing time and memory by applying the context and routing arguments before the actual function call

```
function overview(arg1,arg2,arg3){
  console.info('arg1 is ' + arg1);
  console.info('arg2 is ' + arg2);
  console.info('arg3 is ' + (arg3 || this.foo));
}
var context = { foo:'bar' };
var contextOverview = overview.bind(context);
var modOverview = function(){}.apply.bind(overview.bind(context), context);

modOerview(['test1','test1'])
```

A closure'd variant might look something like:

```
var importModule = (function(){
  var mods = {
    overview:function(arg1,arg2,arg3){
      console.info('arg1 is ' + arg1);
      console.info('arg2 is ' + arg2);
      console.info('arg3 is ' + (arg3 || this.foo()));
      console.warn('This context is ' + this);
    }
  };
  return function exportMod(name, context){
    var mod = mods[name].bind(context);
    return mod.apply.bind(mod,null);
  }
})();

var myContext = (function(){
  var foo = 'bar';
  var overview;
  var context = {
    overview:function(){ return overview() },
    foo:function(){ return foo },
    toString:function(){ return 'my context!' }
  };
  overview = importModule('overview', context);
  return context;
})();

myContext.overview(['test1','test2']);
```

That being said, why don't you just call the function like normal? I mean, if you know the context and the function name.... .. .