# Executing function from string using window not working

Tags: javascript, string, function

I'm trying to execute a function using a string containing the functions name.

[Several](http://www.sitepoint.com/call-javascript-function-string-without-using-eval/) [resources](http://www.roelvanlisdonk.nl/?p=2834) [I've](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string) [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9414830/calling-arbitrary-function-with-javascript-apply) suggest something like this:

```
function runMe(){alert("fail"));
var fnstring = "runMe";
var fn = window[fnstring];
fn();
```

However, it doesn't work at all for me ([JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brentonstrine/ykwrmkLc/1/)). I end up with `fn` as undefined. Am I doing something wrong, or has `window` behavior changed?

Comment: Is `runMe` function defined in a global scope? "using a string containing the functions name" --- any chance to reconsider this "design"? It smells.

Comment: Hm, I'm not quite sure how jsfiddle works... maybe not...

Comment: by default it's not. Switch to `No wrap - in body` in the left 2nd dropdown.

Comment: Dah, ok that was it, thanks!

Comment: Ok, now I've got it working (with arguments) in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brentonstrine/ykwrmkLc/2/), but when I paste it into a `<script></script>` in the body of my dev page, it breaks with error: "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function".

Comment: let's go back to my very first question: Is `runMe` function defined in a global scope?

Comment: Yes. It's the very first thing in the script.

Comment: then it should work the same way jsfiddle does.

Comment: Actually, I just noticed that even though it works in JSFiddle, it still gives this error: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` error because of hoisting. Looking at the first link you provided, there was one key difference between your version and theirs: the conditional.

[Your (second) version](http://jsfiddle.net/brentonstrine/ykwrmkLc/2/):

```
function runMe(thething) {
    alert("the function has successfully run: " + thething);
}

// function we want to run
var fnstring = "runMe";
alert("string: " + fnstring);

// find object
var fn = window[fnstring]("lkjlksdfsdfj");
alert("function: " + fn);

// is object a function?
alert("is function?: " + typeof fn === "function");
fn();
```

[My version, working without errors](http://jsfiddle.net/g64fLcg0/):

```
function runMe(thething) {
    console.log("the function has successfully run: " + thething);
}

// function we want to run
var fnstring = "runMe";

// find object
var fn = window[fnstring]("lkjlksdfsdfj");

// is object a function?
if (typeof fn === "function") fn();
```

The reason why your version throws an error is that it is being hoisted into something like this:

```
function runMe(thething) {
    alert("the function has successfully run: " + thething);
}

var fnstring, fn;

fn();

fnstring = "runMe";
fn = window[fnstring]("lkjlksdfsdfj");
```

So when it's called it *isn't* a function; it's an undefined variable.

On the other hand, as far as I understand hoisting, my version gets hoisted something like this:

```
function runMe(thething) {
    console.log("the function has successfully run: " + thething);
}

var fnstring, fn;
fnstring =  = "runMe";
fn = window[fnstring]("lkjlksdfsdfj");

if (typeof fn === "function") fn();
```

So that by the time the function is actually called, everything's good to go.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Man, I really need to get more familiar with how hoisting works. Cheers!

Comment: Yeah, it's the source of SO many issues I run into that seem to be coming "out of nowhere".