# Passing multiple parameters to a function via a function

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to pass multiple ( unknown ) parameters to a function without using an `Array`?

Take a look at this example code.

```
var test = function( /* Arguments */ ) { // Number 3
    something( /* All Arguments Here */ );
};


var something = function( first, last, age ) { // Number 2
    alert( first + last + age );
};


test('John', 'Smith', 50); // Number 1
```

So the question...

> Is it possible to pass the parameters from `Number 1` TO `Number 2` VIA `Number 3` without affecting the way it's used. ie. without an `Array`.

This could be something to do with `OCD` but using an array would be nasty looking.

Have I tried anything? **Nope**, there is nothing i can think of that i can try so....  what can I try? I have searched.....

Comment: Good question. Is this similar to what you're after? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676721/calling-dynamic-function-with-dynamic-parameters-in-javascript

Comment: It's hard to tell right now, I'm looking into it...

Comment: With which purpose are you trying to implement such a thing?

Comment: @DanielvanDommele that would not be a simple thing to answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var test = function() { // Number 3
    something.apply(null, arguments);
};


var something = function( first, last, age ) { // Number 2
    alert( first + last + age );
};


test('John', 'Smith', 50); // Number 1
```

Comment: That is a nifty little trick, I always use `call` so it wouldn't have worked, but because `apply` accepts an array it does. Thank you very much..

Answer (score 2):

I have found the answer to this, thanks to Blade-something

You would use `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)`

```
var test = function( /* Arguments */ ) {
    something.apply(null, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
};


var something = function( first, last, age ) {
    alert( first + last + age );
};


test('John', 'Smith', 50);
```

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lb8L8/1/)

This example is very useful if you wan't the rest of the arguments and wan't to keep the first one for internal use like so

```
var test = function( name ) {
    // Do something with name
    something.apply(null, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
};
```