# Javascript pass some arguments through middleware, untouched

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

I have a middle ware that looks like this:

```
function(middleWareData) { // has more args, middleware doesn't know how many
    if(middleWareData.passes()) {
        origFunction(/* call with the rest of the args? */
    }
}
```

I'm not actually sure the best way to pop off the first argument from `arguments` then pass the rest to the original function. The original function is very dynamic (it's a connector, either to RabbitMQ which uses 4 arguments, or Redis which uses 2, or a unit test driver which just needs 1) so the middleware doesn't know how many arguments it's actually going to receive.

Using this: `var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(args, 1)` seems like a good start to get the true arguments. However, I believe I just turned arguments 2 through however many into one argument, that's going to be passed as an array to the first variable. Not what I want. How to do this right?

Comment: and/or http://stackoverflow.com/q/17920090/218196

Comment: @FelixKling yes, was missing `apply`. First is good.

Comment: Btw, ES6 introduces rest parameters, where, instead of slicing the arguments object, you can do `function foo(first, ...args)`. Can be quite handy.

Answer (score 0):

You pretty much nailed how to get the correct arguments (excluding the first one). To send the arguments array to the next function, you simply have to `.apply()` the new array to the original function.

`apply()` is a method of the Function prototype *(`Function.prototype.apply`)*, so it can be called on any function. It accepts two arguments: the context *(or `this`)* for that call, and an `Array` that will be used for the arguments of that function call. Based on your code, I assumed that the function was run in the global context, so the first argument is set to `null`.

```
function(middleWareData) {
    if (middleWareData.passes()) {
        origFunction.apply(null, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    }
}
```