# Pass object as parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
$('.helloWorld').on('click', function() {
    $(this).css('background', 'black'); 
});
```

Instead, I would like to do something like this (for research):

```
var params = [
    'click',
    function () {
        $(this).css('background', 'black');
    }
];

$('.helloWorld').on(params);
```

I get an error that reads, "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token , ."

Is this possible?  If so, how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling dynamic function with dynamic parameters in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676721/calling-dynamic-function-with-dynamic-parameters-in-javascript)

Comment: I think you need to use something like `$.fn.on.apply($(".selector"), params);`, but I may be off

Comment: The question is, why do you use an array? As long as the array looks like that, with only one event, you can use `apply`, but it seems much easier to use an object, that way you could add as many events and callbacks as you want ?

Comment: @adeneo Maybe that's the "for research" part? Either way, you're right, they should understand the "better" way

Comment: I really don't like the posted answers, and think it should be done like this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/37xp6srj/**

Comment: @adeneo Agreed, I think that's the *best* way. But again, I think the OP was wondering how to do it with an array. I'd post that as an answer though

Comment: @adeneo I actually like yours better, too!  Thanks.  Only problem with it is if I want to pass additional vars such as `on('click', 'tr', function(){})`.  Any idea for such a scenario?

Comment: Sure, you'd pass that in after the map, like this `$('.helloWorld').on(params, 'tr');`

Comment: @adeneo Thanks; looks like Paulpro's solution may be better here `$.fn.on.apply( $('.helloWorld'), params );` since I can just pass an array of params.  However, that is not a common scenario so I still like your solution more. Post as answer and i'll accept, please

Answer (score 4):

You can use [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to call a function using an array as the arguments, you need to specify the `thisArg` though:

```
$.fn.on.apply( $('.helloWorld'), params );
```

Comment: Why not just reference `$.fn.on` instead of storing the selector results?

Answer (score 3):

You are using an array in your example.  Use an object instead (`{}` instead of `[]`) Something like this should work:

```
var params = {
    "event" : 'click',
    "callback" : function () {
        $(this).css('background', 'black');
    }
};

$('.helloWorld').on(params.event, params.callback);
```

Comment: They are purposefully using an array. The question isn't about how to do it differently. It's very possible with an array, as Paulpro has shown. I'm not saying this is a bad alternative, but it doesn't really answer the question. And if they are going to use an object literal, it would make more sense to use `var params = { on: function () { .... } }; $("").on(params);`

Comment: Understood but are they purposefully using an array?  OP never said that.

Comment: Hmmm, reading it again, you're right. It wasn't as direct/specific as I remembered. Especially because they said "for research". I guess what I'm more referring to is the fact that they seem to want to pass **one** parameter (it's the title, technically) to the `.on()` call - that seems purposeful. Your answer still uses two parameters, it just happens to store them in a single place, instead of two vars.