# How call a dynamic function that is into a JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, function, call

I have the same question that: [Calling dynamic function with dynamic parameters in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676721/calling-dynamic-function-with-dynamic-parameters-in-javascript)

But, with a little change:
I need to call a function, and send a parameter dinamically.

Let's suppouse:

```
var fun = 'theFunction';
var value = '123';
```

I can run it properly doing:

```
window[fun].apply(null, [value]);
```

But, what if my function is:

```
var fun = 'someNamespace.utils.theFunction';
```

If I do:

```
window[fun].apply(null, [value]);
```

I get:

```
TypeError: window[fun] is undefined
```

What can i Do to solve that issue?