# Javascript: how to dynamically call a method and dynamically set parameters for it

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I am trying test out in javascript can dynamically call a method and dynamically set parameters for it.

```
let obj = {
  method: 'foo1',
  params: ['one', 'two']
}

foo 1(p1, p2) {
 // do something
}
```

To run it =>

```
[obj.method](obj.params)
```

Is there any way to dynamically add params from an array.

Comment: You're looking for either `.call` or `.apply` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply `obj.method.call(obj.method, obj.params);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling dynamic function with dynamic parameters in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676721/calling-dynamic-function-with-dynamic-parameters-in-javascript)

Comment: @briosheje I don't think you understood the question. `obj.method` isn't going to work because that is a string and you can't use `call` or `apply` or `bind` on a string.

Comment: @ScottMarcus wops, you're right, you need to invoke through `window`, unless it belongs to something else. I thought the question was about passing dynamic arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For call function by string name:

```
window[obj.method](...obj.params)
```

Example:

```
let obj = {
    method: 'foo1',
    params: ['one', 'two']
}

function foo1(p1, p2) {
    console.log(p1, p2)
}

window[obj.method](...obj.params) // result: one two
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes - spreading (ES6):

```
window[obj.method](...obj.params);
```

Make sure you're accessing the function correctly - if you declare it with `var` in the global scope, it'll be bound to the `window`. If not, it won't be accessible at all (bar `eval`, and that's bad practice).

Answer (score 2):

You'll need the function to exist as a method of an object then you can invoke it dynamically with bracket notation `[]` and pass the name of the method as a string into the brackets as an index. You'll then use the spread operator `...` to flatten the parameter array into a delimited list.

Others have shown this with the global `window` as the parent object, but (as we know) globals are generally bad, so just create your own.

Below, I am showing multiple methods and parameter choices and asking the user to type in which combination they want. Of course this input could be handled in many other ways.

```js
// The methods must be stored in an object so that they can be accessed with
// bracket notation later.
let obj = {
  method1: function foo1(p1, p2) {
            console.log("method1 was called with: ", arguments);
  },
  method2: function foo1(p1, p2) {
            console.log("method2 was called with: ", arguments);
  },
  params1: ['one', 'two'],
  params2: ['three', 'four'],  
};

// Get the user's desired invocation requirements:
let choice = prompt("Enter 'method1' or 'method2'");
let args = prompt("Enter 'params1' or 'params2'");

// Pass the method name (as a string) into the object to extract the
// value of that property. Then invoke it with () and look up the correct
// parameter property in the same way. Flatten the parameter array with the
// spread operator (...).
obj[choice](...obj[args]);
```